# ¿Esperar a que retrofit responda un llamado?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Tengo que hacer un Retrofit Call dentro de un adapter para comparar información de dos arraylist:

```
public void checkguardadas(int id_usuario) {

    RetrofitService retrofitService = RetrofitService.getInstance();
    PabloAPI api = retrofitService.getApiProxyServer();
     Call<ArrayList<Oferta>> call = api.getGuardadas(1);

     call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Oferta>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Oferta>> call, Response<ArrayList<Oferta>> response) {

            Log.d("traza", "por aqui");
            Log.d("traza", response.body().toString());
            guardadas = response.body();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Oferta>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("traza", "por alla");
            Log.d("traza", t.toString());
        }
    });
```

Y así, llamo a esto despues.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final OfertasAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder, 
int i) {
    Iterator it = guardadas.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (ofertaList.get(i).getId() == guardadas.get(i).getId()) {
            viewHolder.guardar.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
```

El problema es que la llamada no se ejecuta antes de que el codigo se corra, así que da valor nulo y la aplicación no abre. ¿Alguna idea de lo que puedo hacer? He probado varias cosas sin mucha suerte (AsyncTask y una dependencia Rxjava) y también meter todo el adapter dentro de onResponse() pero no sabría hacerlo. Por favor tomar en cuenta que soy un principiante!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit ejecuta el metodo onResponse de manera asincrona por lo que necesitas un evento que se ejecute cuando el metodo onResponse obtenga la respuesta.

Crea una interfaz en tu proyecto, llámala `OnOfertasResponse`:

```
public interface OnOfertasResponse
{
    void ofertas(ArrayList<Oferta> ofertas);
}
```

El metodo `ofertas` se ejecutara cuando obtengas las ofertas del servidor. A esto se le llama callback.

Ahora modifica el metodo `checkguardadas` para que acepte el callback y en el metodo onResponse ejecutamos el metodo `ofertas`:

```
public void checkguardadas(int id_usuario, OnOfertasResponse callback) {
    RetrofitService retrofitService = RetrofitService.getInstance();
    PabloAPI api = retrofitService.getApiProxyServer();
    Call<ArrayList<Oferta>> call = api.getGuardadas(1);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Oferta>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Oferta>> call, Response<ArrayList<Oferta>> response) {

            Log.d("traza", "por aqui");
            Log.d("traza", response.body().toString());

            // ejecutamos el callback
            callback.ofertas(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Oferta>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("traza", "por alla");
            Log.d("traza", t.toString());
        }
    }); 
}
```

Entonces para utilizar esto solo tendras que enviar el callback al metodo `checkguardadas`:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final OfertasAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    // le enviamos el callback al metodo checkguardadas
    checkguardadas(11,new OnOfertasResponse(){

        @Override
        public void ofertas(ArrayList<Oferta> ofertas){
            // este metodo se ejecutara cuando onResponse se ejecute
            Iterator it = ofertas.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                if (ofertaList.get(i).getId() == ofertas.get(i).getId()) {
                    viewHolder.guardar.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funciona perfecto. ¡Eres un crack!